# In Big O notation, how do you factor in calls to other methods?

Tags: c++, big-o

Hypothetically, lets say we have these two methods:

```
void example(int p){
    p += 10;
    p = exampleTwo(p);
}

int exampleTwo(int p){
    int pp = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < p; i++){
        pp++;
    }
    return pp;
}
```

The method `exampleTwo` has a linear runtime. Its run time is O(n).

So, what is the big O notation of the method `example`, taking into account that it calls `exampleTwo`?

I would imagine it is also O(n), but I do not know for sure.

Comment: It's O(n). Don't think of it like functions, think of it like an algorithm, with arbitrary amounts of functions.

Comment: Sorry, I was taught to do big O notation using the variable `n`. In this case, it represents the number of times the loop will cycle. It is the variable I use for the number of operations when the number of cycles will be unknown.

Comment: You're using it right, more or less :). The function is linear with respect to the input variable `p`. So, `O(p)`, but `n` is often used, so it's kind of implicit.

Comment: I think to better understand big O notation you should find a graph of the real performance of some algorithm, then use the mathematical definition of big O, big theta, and big omega to try out some candidates. Then ask yourself if it matters if that performance data is from an implementation that uses functions or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`example()` has no loop, it does nothing extra to `exampleTwo()` so it has the same order of complexity, i.e. `O(n)`, as `exampleTwo()`.

---

If `example()` is changed to this:

```
int example(int p){
  int sum = 0;
  for(int i=0; i<p; ++i){
    sum += exampleTwo(p);
    }
  return sum;
}
```

then the complexity is now `O(n²)`: as `p` gets bigger the amount of work to do increases by the square of `p`.

Answer (score 6):

For subroutines, you should multiply the order by the order of the number of the number of times it is called. For example, if a function is called O(n) times, and runs in O(log n) time, the total order is O(n log n).